# how to merge an array

Tags: php, arrays

using the code below

```
$matchs = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Match')->whereBetween('date_access', [$request->from, $request->to])->get();
foreach ($matchs as $key => $match) {
    $array[] = [
        $match->status => $match->date_access,
    ];
}
dd($array);
```

i get the output
[image]

now i want to merge the 4 arrays to 1.. how can i do that? my ouuput should be `array:1> date => value`

i have tried array_merge() and array_push() and it didnt work

Comment: use `array_merge`

Comment: @codekaizeri mentioned i used it and it isnt working

Comment: @codekaizer but "_it didn't work_"

Comment: Check the answer below. @JohnDoe

Comment: what is expected outout ?

Comment: @MayankMajithya    `date => value` in only one array

Comment: please update in question, what exact output you want

Comment: i don't get this `$array[] = [$match->status => $match->date_access];`

Comment: @codekaizer that is currently how im trying to create the array.. it will output as the picture i posted

Answer (score 0):

for example using recursive array iterator from spl

```
$array = array(array(1,2,3),array(5,6,7),array(8,9,10));
$mergedArray = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach ($mergedArray as $a) {
   echo $a; // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
}
```

and that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

here is how u can use array_merge().

```
$arr = array(

    0 => array(1 ,2 ,3),
    1 => array(4, 5, 6),
    2 => array(7, 8, 9)
);

$allInOne = array();

foreach ($arr as $value) {

    $allInOne = array_merge($allInOne, $value);
}

var_dump($allInOne); // the output [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

This code will merge you all arrays in one this is just what you want i guess
```